# Getting the maximum value of balances from different employee ids

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a problem in using SELECT statement I want to SELECT the Maximum Balances Per Employee ID. I have a table like this.

```
EMPLOYE ID |  BALANCES
  c50-5050   |    100
  c50-5050   |    200
**c50-5050   |    300**
  c50-5051   |    200
**c50-5051   |    300**
```

The one with the asterisk indicates what I want to SELECT from the table.

I actually need this to show in a datagrid view in VB.net. Do you have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: Give a try `SELECT   MAX(BALANCES) FROM my_table GROUP BY EMPLOYE ID`

Answer (score 3):

use below query

```
select max(Balances),employe_id from table
group by employe_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` with `OVER`-clause:

```
WITH X AS
(
   SELECT [EMPLOYE ID], BALANCES,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [EMPLOYE ID] ORDER BY BALANCES DESC)
   FROM dbo.Table
)
SELECT EMPLOYE ID, BALANCES
FROM X
WHERE RN = 1
```

> I actually need this to show in a datagrid view in VB.net. Do you have
>   an idea on how to do this?

Use ADO.NET, you could use a `DataAdapter` to fill a `DataTable`:

```
Dim table = New DataTable()
Dim sql = "see sql above"
Using con = New SqlConnection(yourConnectionString)
    Using da = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, con)
       da.Fill(table)
    End Using
End Using
DataGridView1.DataSource = table
```

Comment: Is the more modern `ROW_NUMBER` approach to be preferred over an oldschool `MAX` and `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @AakashM: It's simpler and easier to maintain. You can also select all columns as opposed to a `GROUP BY` where each colum must be aggregated. Note that you can use any aggregate function with the [`OVER`-clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx), e.g. `MaxBalance=MAX(BALANCES)OVER(PARTITION BY  [EMPLOYE ID])`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,MAX(balances) FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

A `max()` `group by` query should do it

```
select max(balance), employe_id
from yourTable
group by employe_id
```